# Printing a character specific line equivalent to string in Java

Tags: java, methods, char, underline

To keep it short and concise I'm attempting to write a program that not only turns user input into a title. but also prints out a user generated decorative underline beneath the output. 
example;

"prompt to get user input"

input: i am a title, *

output:

```
I Am A Title
* ** * *****
```

I was thinking of using a method that receives a String and a char and uses that to calculate the number of chars it has to output. I was already able to get the title to output in capitals thanks to a post here. Now it's just the characters. Even if it's just ways to think about the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: with decorative, you also mean fancy colored letters or just the line under it?

Comment: Just the line made with the character. I was able to do it already though with the help of another user. Still, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void printUnderline(String s, char c){
    char[] arr =s.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        if(arr[i] == ' ')
            System.out.print(' ');
        else
            System.out.print(c);
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective, Thank you.

Comment: First thing I tried but I don't have the reputation for it yet. When I do I will. :)

Comment: @JohnFranklinGomez If this is not the answer, what do you expect than this in order to accept this as the answer ?

Comment: @JudeNiroshan he meant.. he wants to accept, but can't. :)

Comment: Yup, I can't vote up on an answer until I gain more reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String str = "i am a title";
        String aux = "";
        String[]titles = str.split(" ");

        for(int i=0; i<titles.length;i++){
            aux += titles[i].replaceFirst(titles[i].charAt(0)+"", Character.toUpperCase(titles[i].charAt(0))+"") + " ";
        }

        System.out.println(aux);
        if(str.contains(" ")){
            aux = str;
            aux = aux.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]",  "*");

            System.out.println(aux);

        }else{
            System.out.println(false);
        }
```